# SCNRenderer on iOS get error when allocating

Tags: ios, opengl-es, scenekit

I'm creating SCNRenderer on iOS for offscreen rendering and I don't know why i get error saying:

"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)"

The only thing in my code is creating of this "SCNRenderer". This function call in viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
    openGLContext = EAGLContext(API: .OpenGLES2)
    var renderer = SCNRenderer(context: &openGLContext, options: nil)
    
}
```

I checked openGLContext, it isn't nil

I also checked, SCNRenderer available on iOS 8

> rendererWithContext:options:
>
> context: An OpenGL rendering context: either a CGLContextObj reference (in OS X) or an EAGLContext object (in iOS).

Why do you think am i getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: this code is much smaller and appears to work great:

```
let renderer = SCNRenderer(context: unsafeBitCast(eaglContext, UnsafeMutablePointer.self), options: nil)
```

--OLD ANSWER FOLLOWS--

For now I just use this workaround Objective-C class.

```
@import SceneKit;

@interface SCNRenderer (SwiftiOSWorkaround)
+ (instancetype)rendererWithContextObject:(EAGLContext *)eaglContext options:(NSDictionary *)options;
@end

@implementation SCNRenderer (SwiftiOSWorkaround)
+ (instancetype)rendererWithContextObject:(EAGLContext *)eaglContext options:(NSDictionary *)options;
{
    return [self rendererWithContext:(__bridge void *)eaglContext options:options];
}
@end
```

You can then create an SCNRenderer from Swift using:

```
var renderer = SCNRenderer(contextObject: openGLContext, options: nil)
```

Comment: Yes, i kept it reference to openGLContext, but it still crash.

Comment: Ok, I tried it myself and I'm also seeing the crash. I've reported it to the correct groups at Apple and we should see an API change.

Answer (score 0):

you should not need to pass the address of openGLContext. It's a pointer to an EAGLContext object.

`var renderer = SCNRenderer(context: openGLContext, options: nil)`

Comment: SCNRenderer(context: openGLContext, options: nil) take an UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>

when i pass the pointer, i got an error
EAGLContext is not convertible to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>'